# Search value in dataGridview1, Form1 by entering the value in

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, search-box

I am trying to search a value located on dataGridView1, Form1 by entering the value in textbox in Form2.DataGridView1 is set to load data from a .xls file.

I know there is some code missing in Form1 and Form2 in order to perform this task, that is because i am new to Visual Studio and C# code.

Thank you very much for your help :)

This is code located in Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Plan_de_lucru
{
    public partial class frPlanDeLucru : Form
    {
        public frPlanDeLucru()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ctrlLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string constr = "Provider = MicroSoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + TextBox1.Text + "; Extended Properties =\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;\";";
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + textBox2.Text + "$]", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            new Form2().Show();
            this.Show();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {


            }
        }


    }
```

This is the code located in Form2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Plan_de_lucru
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void search_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String str = "select * from searchBox where ( Name like '%' + @search + '%')";
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
            bs.Parameters.Add("@search",)



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use the form's name to call the objects, for example in form2, the data source would be `bs.DataSource = frPlanDeLucru.dataGridView1.DataSource`

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I get an error that states :CS0122 'frPlanDeLucru.dataGridView1' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Solved it, it was due to the fact that Form1 was set to private.

Comment: Your code snippet shows it as public so I'm not sure how that makes sense